# How to change the default property on a set in python and Google AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In the following code:

```
class ClassA(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class ClassB(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    deleted_flag = db.BooleanProperty()
    classA = db.ReferenceProperty(ClassA)
```

ClassA will have a property called `classb_set`.  When I call `classb_set` within code, I do not want it to return items that have the `deleted_flag = true`.

How can I change the default filter on the `classb_set` query?  My first instinct is to create another method in ClassA that does this filter, but is there a way that keeps the `classb_set` a property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use a Python property to accomplish your goal:

```
class ClassA(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

    def __get_classBdeleted(self):
        return self.classB_set.filter('deleted_flag =', 'True')

    classBdeleted = property(__get_classBdeleted)

class ClassB(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    deleted_flag = db.BooleanProperty()
    classA = db.ReferenceProperty(ClassA)
```